# Can't say Hello World in node

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am trying to follow the following the tutorial The [Node Beginner Book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/#structure)

I have installed node and mongodb successfully, when i do `node -v` it gives me `v0.5.11-pre` but when i save the file say `hello.js` in `Home/node/` and write `node hello.js` in the terminal it gives me the following error

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ node hello.js

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^ Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/Downloads/hello.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Please help me find what I am doing wrong here. I'm using Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Comment: Check your filenames. To me it seems that your trying to run something that does not exist.

Comment: @Kirstein that should be an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the wrong directory. Move to the file where `hello.js` is with [`cd`](http://ss64.com/bash/cd.html), like this:

```
cd $HOME/node
node hello.js
```